# COUNTIF with Multiplicities

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am currently creating a histogram on Google Sheets to count how many of x-product in our inventory we have priced at less than $10k, between $10k to $20k, $20k to $30k, etc.

[image]

The problem is that some our products have multiplicities greater than 1 —we have two of x-product priced at $50k for example.

[image]

Thus the normal `COUNTIFS` function is not picking up these multiplicities and undercounting them. Here's the `COUNTIF` function I'm using:

```
=COUNTIFS(J5:J50,">=10000", J5:J50,"<20000")
```

I've come across the `SUMPRODUCT` function, and have read it can work with other functions, so I think a solution may lie here. I'm using:

> `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(J5:J50,">=10000", J5:J50,"<20000"),F5:F50)`

However, I'm gettin `#VALUE` returned with the following message:

[image]

Anybody who can provide clarity on what I'm doing wrong or direct me to another function that can solve the problem, it would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @marikamitsos Will do, not at computer now. Will check out it works when back. Thanks for response & comment

Answer (score 1):

Please try this formula:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF(
       (F5:F55>0) * (J5:J55>=50000) * (J5:J55<70000),F5:F55,0)))
```

> ***Pro tip***

**Instead of editing the formula every time** you want a different range, you can use the following formula and **use** the values you enter in **cells `K1`** and **`L1`** respectively.

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF(
       (F5:F55>0) * (J5:J55>=K2) * (J5:J55<L2),F5:F55,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.